# Salt Stack Installation Issue

Tags: salt-stack

I'm trying to install Salt Stack Open Source. I keep getting these errors when i'm trying to install using 'yum'

```
yum install https://repo.saltstack.com/yum/redhat/salt-repo-latest-2.el7.noarch.rpm
Cannot open: https://repo.saltstack.com/yum/redhat/salt-repo-latest-2.el7.noarch.rpm. Skipping.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I tried installing using bootstarp script but getting these errors

```
Peer received a valid certificate, but access was denied
```

I have disabled the firewall on the server but looks like the perimeter firewall is stopping something. Need suggestions.

Comment: Could you try to use the following command ? `wget https://repo.saltstack.com/yum/redhat/salt-repo-latest-2.el7.noarch.rpm` as we need to make sure that you can connect to their website correctly without any issues related to validating the secure connection

Comment: @MostafaHussein: Thanks for your help. It was our FW blocking so had to use a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Issue Solved! The issue was indeed with the firewall so my IT team set a proxy and it went all good. Thanks for your support guys.